# Entries present in /etc/fstab

Tags: filesystems

I opened the file /etc/fstab and found the following entries only:

```
proc            /proc           proc    nodev,noexec,nosuid      0       0  
/dev/sda5       /boot           ext4    defaults                 0       2
/dev/sda6       none            swap    sw                       0       0
```

At the same time I opened the /proc/filesystems file it is having the following entries:

```
nodev   sysfs  
nodev   rootfs  
nodev   bdev  
nodev   proc  
nodev   cgroup  
nodev   cpuset  
nodev   tmpfs  
nodev   devtmpfs  
nodev   debugfs  
nodev   securityfs  
nodev   sockfs  
nodev   pipefs  
nodev   anon_inodefs  
nodev   devpts  
    ext3  
    ext2  
    ext4  
nodev   ramfs  
nodev   hugetlbfs  
nodev   ecryptfs  
nodev   fuse  
    fuseblk  
nodev   fusectl  
nodev   mqueue  
nodev   binfmt_misc
```

Can somebody please explain me Why all these entries are not present in the /etc/fstab file?

Answer (score 5):

`/proc/filesystems` lists all the filesystem types (drivers if you want) currently available in your kernel.

`/etc/fstab` lists what devices should be mounted on which mount points.

Look at `/proc/mounts`, `/etc/mtab`, or use the `mount` command to see what filesystems are currently mounted.